# Power Shell Script to filter inactive users

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble filtering correctly because when I generate the $Resultado Array, its content is displaced and is not displayed correctly.

Also, I can't display correctly the $Resultado2.

This is what im trying:

```
$Resultado = @() #Just an array to get the users
$Resultado2 = @() #The array with the users filtered

$Usuarios = @(query user | select -skip 1) -split "\n" #Getting the users

    foreach($Usuario in $Usuarios) #Adding the users to the array
    {

        $Parsed = $Usuario -split '\s+'
        $Resultado += [PSCustomObject]@{
            USERNAME = $Parsed[1]
            SESSIONNAME = $Parsed[2]
            ID = $Parsed[3]
            STATE = $Parsed[4]
            IDLE_TIME = $Parsed[5]
            LOGON_TIME = $Parsed[6]
        }

    }

    foreach($Revision in $Resultado){ #Filtering for dissconected users

        if ($Parsed[4] = "Desc"){

            if($Parsed[5] -gt "5"){

            continue
                    
            }

        }

        $Parsed2 = $Revision -split '\s+'
        $Resultado2 += [PSCustomObject] @{
            USERNAME2 = $Parsed2[1]
            STATE2 = $Parsed2[4]
            IDLE_TIME2 = $Parsed2[5]
        }
    }


$Resultado | Format-Table
```

This is the expected result of $Resultado

[image: Expected Image]

This is what i get

[image: Result]

Thanks to a reply I notices that the array was started badly so i change it for this:

```
foreach($Usuario in $Usuarios) #Adding the users to the array
    {

        $Parsed = $Usuario -split '\s+'
        $Resultado += [PSCustomObject]@{
            USERNAME = $Parsed[0]
            SESSIONNAME = $Parsed[1]
            ID = $Parsed[2]
            STATE = $Parsed[3]
            IDLE_TIME = $Parsed[4]
            LOGON_TIME = $Parsed[5]
        }
```

But im still not getting what i expect because the second user is moved due to a blanc in SESSIONAME

[image: Result after change]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final script if you need something like that

```
# Script to close inactive sessions

$fechaActual = Get-Date
$año = $fechaActual.Year
$mes = $fechaActual.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')
$dia = $fechaActual.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')
$hora = $fechaActual.Hour.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')
$minuto = $fechaActual.Minute.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')
$segundo = $fechaActual.Second.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')

$fechaNumerica = "${año}${mes}${dia}_${hora}${minuto}${segundo}"

$path="Your path"
Out-File -FilePath $path

if (Test-Path -Path "Your path" -PathType Leaf) {
   if ((Get-Content -Path "Your path with the computers" -Raw).Trim().Length -gt 0) {
        
        # Get actial time
        
        Add-Content $path "******************************************************"
        Add-Content $path "$fechaActual"
        $file = Get-Content "Your path with the computers"
        #$file = Get-Content "Your path with the computers"

    foreach ($pc in $file) 
    {
        Add-Content $path "******************************************************"
        Add-Content $path "$pc"
        # Obtain list of connected users

        try {
           $resultado = Test-Connection -ComputerName $pc -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop
           Write-Host "El host $pc es accesible. Tiempo de respuesta: $($resultado.ResponseTime) ms"

        $usuarios = query user /server:$pc

        # Filtering only discotected users
        $usuariosDesconectados = $usuarios | Where-Object { $_ -match 'Disc' -or $_ -match 'Desc'}

            if ($usuariosDesconectados -ne $null -and $usuariosDesconectados.Trim().Length -gt 0) {
                foreach ($lineaUsuario in $usuariosDesconectados) { 
                   #Write-Output $lineaUsuario
                   
                   $columnas = $lineaUsuario -split '\s+'

                   # Obtain user name and last Connection
                   $nombreUsuario = $columnas[1]
                   $idUsuario = $columnas[2]
                   $ultimaConexion = $columnas[5] + " " + $columnas[6]
                   $ultimaConexionDateTime = Get-Date $ultimaConexion
                   $tiempoTranscurrido = ($fechaActual - $ultimaConexionDateTime).TotalMinutes
                   # Look if X time passed
                   if ($tiempoTranscurrido -gt 120) {
                       Add-Content $path "Cerrando sesión debido a tiempo de inactividad."
                       Add-Content $path "$nombreUsuario"
                       #Write-Output "Cerrando sesión debido a tiempo de inactividad."
                       logoff $idUsuario /server:$pc
                    }
                }
              
            } else {
              Add-Content $path "No tiene sesiones inactivas"
            }

        } catch {
           Add-Content $path "El host $pc no es accesible. Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You're starting to count `$parsed` at [1], the name is at `$parsed[0]`, all your `$parsed` indexes are off by 1.

Also by the time you're going into `foreach($Revision in $Resultado)` you're not ever touching `$parsed` again, as such you'll always be checking the state and `idle_time` of the very last User of `$Usarios`

Comment: Thaks, already noticed that